# Writing Visual Studio Code Syntaxes in Monarch

Tags: visual-studio-code, visual-studio-monaco

The [VSCode documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/customization/colorizer) contains details on how to create new colorizers using `.tmLanguage` files. The Monaco editor which VSCode uses has support for defining syntax highlighters using the [JSON-based Monarch format](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/monarch.html), but I can't see how to use Monarch for defining syntaxes in VSCode extensions.

Is there a way to define a new VSCode syntax using the Monarch format rather than textmate style language files?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, VSCode currently only supports the `.tmLanguage` format. To quote one of the team members in [#216](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/216#issuecomment-222501886):

> First we had Monarch support as well, but before the API deadline decided to go fully for text mate to keep the API simple.