# Migrating Monarch language to VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, visual-studio-monaco, monarch

VSCode [doesn't support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37936919/writing-visual-studio-code-syntaxes-in-monarch) the Monarch grammar in Monaco. I would like to implement syntax highlight in VSCode for a language which has a Monarch syntax highlight. Is there a good way to do so? Or do I have to write the grammar from scratch myself?